# Webpack code-splitting when importing dynamic and static mixed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, code-splitting

I have a problem with code splitting in webpack 5.
I have a monorepo with yarn workspaces. Package `foo` contains a very large component (`Foo`). It also contains some small static stuff (`theme`), which shouldn't be loaded lazy.
As I want to have a small main chunk, this should only contain the small `theme` and nothing else. `Foo` should later be imported "lazy".

What webpack actually does is import all things in the main chunk, at the moment the index.tsx file contains the `theme` import and the dynamic import is kind of ignored. There are two chunks, but the second one is just empty.

foo.ts

```js
export { Foo as default } from "foo";
```

index.tsx

```js
import React, { Suspense} from "react";
import { theme } from "foo";
export const App = () => {
    const Foo = React.lazy(() => import("./foo"));
    return <>
        {theme}
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
            <Foo />
        </Suspense>
    </>;
};
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Is it the same on the production mode?

Comment: You have to change your directory structure so that `theme` is not coupled to `Foo` and you can `import { theme }` from a different module/file.

Comment: @morganney I'm not sure if it's practical to move every part which could have it's own chunk in a seperate package

Comment: I said file not package. The way you have them defined in the same module doesn't work as you say. Change your webpack `entry` to make them separate bundles or dynamically import `theme` from within `Foo`.